# Expo React Native IOS TestFlight. (Errors occurred in the app thinning process)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight, app-thinning

When I try to deploy my application on the Apple test flight I get this email from apple.

> While processing your iOS app, xxxxxxx 1.0.149(1), errors occurred
> in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your
> app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have failed. Because of
> these errors, this build of your app will not be able to be submitted
> for review or placed on the App Store. For information that may help
> resolve this issue, see [Tech Note 2432](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html).

But the problem was I did deploy this application day before without any issues using Transporter.
I spend more than 20hr searching for answers for this issue but had no luck.

Can someone guide me on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: To enable/disable bitcode support go to Project > Build Settings > search for 'bitcode' in the searchfield > set to YES/NO.  try to disable it then upload without bitcode

Comment: Is the above possible for an app build using React native? The above looks like it's specific to Xcode builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it this link for more understanding.

https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-managed-app-cant-get-submitted-to-apple-appstore-due-to-app-thinning/62231

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4253

Answer (score 3):

Rebuilt and submitted with Classic expo build:ios and now it's approved and working.

I was facing the same issue yesterday and although I tried enable/disable bitcode, expo build was failing after added bitcode.
I tried eas build too .. it's still rejecting from submission with app thinning error.